# How can I show only 1 id?

Tags: php, html, sql

I need to show only 1 id at the same time, and I need a button to go to the previous and next id , how can I do that?
And when I click "Aanpassen" I want to edit only the id, but when I click "Aanpassen" now it shows me every id. How can I fix this?
These are my codes:

Overzichtbetalingen.php

```
<?php  include ('betalingen.php'); ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Overzichtbetalingen</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="overzichtbetalingen.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <a href="index.html">Startpagina<a/>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Naam</th>
                <th>Pand</th>
                <th>Datum betaling</th>
                <th colspan="2">Hoe word er betaald</th>
                <th>Betalingsperiode</th>
                <th>Bedrag per periode</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)){?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['Naam']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['Pand']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['Datum']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['Betaling']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['Bank']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['Betalingsperiode']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['Bedragperperiode']?></td>
                <?php } ?>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button class="knop" onclick="window.location = ('https://mijntuintjes.000webhostapp.com/Betalingtoevoegen.php') ">Betaling toevoegen</button>
    <div>
    </body>
```

Betalingen.php

> ```
> <?php
> session_start();
> // connect to database
> $db = mysqli_connect("xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx");
> //retrieve results
> $results = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT *  FROM Info");
> ```
>
> ### >     ?>

Betalingsperiode.php

```
<?php
//connect to database
$db = mysqli_connect("xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx");
//show results
$results = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT *  FROM Info");

?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Betalingsperiode</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Betalingsperiode.css">
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Naam</th>
        <th>E-mail</th>
        <th>Betalingsperiode</th>
        <th>Aanpassen</th>
    </tr>
    <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)){ ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['Naam']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['Email']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['Betalingsperiode']?></td>
        <td>
        <a href="Aanpassenbetalingsperiode.php?aanpassen=><?php echo $row['id'] ?>">Aanpassen</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Maand</th>
        <th>Bedragpermaand</th>
        <th>Betaald/Niet betaald</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    <tr>
        <th><?php echo $row['Januari']?></th>
        <td><?php echo $row['Bedragperjan']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['Betaaldjan']?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th><?php echo $row['Februari']?></th>
        <td><?php echo $row['Bedragperfeb']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['Betaaldfeb']?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th><?php echo $row['Maart']?></th>
        <td><?php echo $row['Bedragpermaa']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['Betaaldmaa']?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th><?php echo $row['April']?></th>
        <td><?php echo $row['Bedragperapr']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['Betaaldapr']?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th><?php echo $row['Mei']?></th>
        <td><?php echo $row['Bedragpermei']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['Betaaldmei']?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th><?php echo $row['Juni']?></th>
        <td><?php echo $row['Bedragperjun']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['Betaaldjun']?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th><?php echo $row['Juli']?></th>
        <td><?php echo $row['Bedragperjul']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['Betaaldjul']?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th><?php echo $row['Augustus']?></th>
        <td><?php echo $row['Bedragperaug']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['Betaaldaug']?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th><?php echo $row['September']?></th>
        <td><?php echo $row['Bedragpersep']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['Betaaldsep']?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th><?php echo $row['Oktober']?></th>
        <td><?php echo $row['Bedragperokt']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['Betaaldokt']?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th><?php echo $row['November']?></th>
        <td><?php echo $row['Bedragpernov']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['Betaaldnov']?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th><?php echo $row['December']?></th>
        <td><?php echo $row['Bedragperdec']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['Betaalddec']?></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
</body>
```

Updaten.php

> ```
> <?php
> //connect with my sql
> $con = mysqli_connect("xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx");
> // Select database
> mysqli_select_db($con, 'id12302950_gebruikers');
> //Update Query
> $sql = "UPDATE Info SET Januari = '$_POST[Januari]', Bedragperjan = '$_POST[Bedragperjan]' ,  Betaaldjan = '$_POST[Betaaldjan]', Februari = '$_POST[Februari]', Bedragperfeb = '$_POST[Bedragperfeb]', Betaaldfeb = '$_POST[Betaaldfeb]' ,Maart = '$_POST[Maart]', Bedragpermaa = '$_POST[Bedragpermaa]',Betaaldmaa = '$_POST[Betaaldmaa]',April= '$_POST[April]', Bedragperapr = '$_POST[Bedragperapr]',Betaaldapr = '$_POST[Betaaldapr]',Mei = '$_POST[Mei]', Bedragpermei = '$_POST[Bedragpermei]',Betaaldmei = '$_POST[Betaaldmei]',Juni = '$_POST[Juni]', Bedragperjun = '$_POST[Bedragperjun]',Betaaldjun = '$_POST[Betaaldjun]',Juli = '$_POST[Juli]', Bedragperjul = '$_POST[Bedragperjul]',Betaaldjul = '$_POST[Betaaldjul]',Augustus = '$_POST[Augustus]', Bedragperaug = '$_POST[Bedragperaug]',Betaaldaug = '$_POST[Betaaldaug]', September = '$_POST[September]', Bedragpersep = '$_POST[Bedragpersep]',Betaaldsep = '$_POST[Betaaldsep]',Oktober = '$_POST[Oktober]', Bedragperokt = '$_POST[Bedragperokt]',Betaaldokt = '$_POST[Betaaldokt]',November = '$_POST[November]', Bedragpernov = '$_POST[Bedragpernov]',Betaaldnov = '$_POST[Betaaldnov]',December = '$_POST[December]', Bedragperdec = '$_POST[Bedragperdec]',Betaalddec = '$_POST[Betaalddec]' WHERE id='$_POST[id]'";
> //execute the query
> if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
>     echo("Error description:". mysqli_error($con));
> }
> header('location: Betalingsperiode.php');
> ?>
> ```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use prepared statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can limit your query result and / or fetch only one time:

```
SELECT *  FROM Info LIMIT 1
```

And/or replace:

```
<?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)){ ?>
```

with

```
<?php $row = mysqli_fetch_array($results); ?>
```

and remove the closing `}`

Comment: Thankyou so much! Is it also possible now to create buttons that will go to the next and previous id?

Comment: It's possible but you will need to define how to do the pagination. The easiest way would be to do a second query to get the next and previous id, and then `echo` those buttons with the links.

Comment: Thanks very useful :)